# Issue switching language input

Tags: windows, windows-7

On windows 7 new install I couldn't change language via <kbd>right alt</kbd> +
 <kbd>shift</kbd>.

I could do by the <kbd>left alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>.

I used to change by right alt shift and left alt shift all worked in the previous win7 installation.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the keyboard layout set correctly and is the right Alt in fact an Alt-Gr instead of a plain Alt key?

If you right-click your taskbar I think there may be an option to open your Keyboard and Language options. If I'm not remembering correctly then you can certainly get to it through your Control Panel. You can change the keyboard layout here.

Open a text editor and try typing in the alternate and lesser used keys such as #$/|~` and so on to test if the right keys produce the right characters.

The on screen keyboard can also give you a display of what layout the computer thinks you are using. You can find that in your Accessibility Options.

Comment: how to check or change this

Comment: If you right-click your taskbar I think there may be an option to open your keyboard and language options. If I'm not remembering correctly then you can certainly get to it through your Control Panel.

Comment: i know how to open it but how to know that alt is alt-gr or not and how to change it

Comment: AltGr should produce non Latin characters such as `äöüß`. I think that you might have your keyboard set to US International or some variant. Try setting it to standard US layout which does not include an AltGr key.

Comment: yes it is alt-gr i want it to be alt only not alt-gr how ?

Comment: I believe that the standard English US (non International variety) should not have the right Alt key as AltGr. Research and test it.